# How to create an array with a forward starting structure?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am looking to create an array in python to do matrix multiplication on. The issue is I need to create an array of 1s and 0s that are not simply stacked lower triangles. For example, for a 5 year horizon, this would be the array created:

| 1Y | 2Y | 3Y | 4Y | 5Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Above is every permutation of forward starting swaps for a 5 year horizon, eg. 1Y1Y, 1Y2Y...3Y2Y,4Y1Y
I want to have a function where I just input the max tenor length, eg 5, and it return this array as a dataframe in pandas.

I have created a function that can determine the correct number of rows and columns based on the horizon length, eg 5Y has 10 rows (4+3+2+1=10). The issue is I cannot figure out how to programaticly populate the 1s in the table to include every permutation for these forward starting swaps. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why 1Y is always 0?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`np.tri`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tri.html) to create the triangular patterns in your example, then [`np.vstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) [`np.pad`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)ded versions of each together:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def forward_starting_swaps(n):
    arrs = [
        np.pad(
            np.tri(i, dtype=int),
            ((0, 0), (n-i, 0))
        )
        for i in range(n-1, 0, -1)
    ]

    cols = [f"{i}Y" for i in range(1, n+1)]

    return pd.DataFrame(np.vstack(arrs), columns=cols)

out = forward_starting_swaps(n=5)
```

out:

```
   1Y  2Y  3Y  4Y  5Y
0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   1   0
3   0   1   1   1   1
4   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   1   0
6   0   0   1   1   1
7   0   0   0   1   0
8   0   0   0   1   1
9   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the binary representation of powers of 2 to get the expected output:

```
def f(n):
    arr = np.array([list(np.binary_repr(i, n))
                       for j in range(n)
                       for i in np.cumsum(2**(np.arange(n-j-1, 0, -1)-1))],
                   dtype=np.uint8)
    return pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=[f'{i+1}Y' for i in range(n)])
```

Usage:

```
>>> f(5)
   1Y  2Y  3Y  4Y  5Y
0   0   1   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1   1   0
3   0   1   1   1   1
4   0   0   1   0   0
5   0   0   1   1   0
6   0   0   1   1   1
7   0   0   0   1   0
8   0   0   0   1   1
9   0   0   0   0   1
```